# Assert that all members of an array are equivalent using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write a small piece of test code to remind me that certain collections are equivalent i.e. simple, self-contained, easy to read and LINQ Lambda oriented (to fulfill a personal learning target).

Here's what I have come up with:

```
var e = new IEnumerable<int> [] {
                                    Enumerable.Range(100, 4).ToArray(), 
                                    new int[] { 100, 101, 102, 103 },
                                    new [] { 100, 101, 102, 103 },
                                    Enumerable.Range(100, 4).ToList(), 
                                    new List<int> { 100, 101, 102, 103 }
                                };

var permutations = e.SelectMany(s => e, ( lhs, rhs ) => new { lhs,  rhs })
                    .Where( x => !x.lhs.Equals ( x.rhs ) ); 

foreach (var item in permutations)
{
    Assert.That( item.lhs, Is.EqualTo( item.rhs ) );
}
```

- Q1. Is there a 'simple' alteration to yield 10 combinations of pairs (I currently have 20 permutations of pairs)? By 'simple' I mean using existing LINQ operators, rather than, say writing a recursive extension method.
- Q2. Is there a better way of asserting "all members of the array are equivalent" in context?

---

As regards Q1, this would seem to give me the right-hand side (rhs) but how to I 'carry-through' (or rejoin to) the 'original' to give me the left-hand side (lhs)?:

```
var r = e.SelectMany(( e1, i ) => e.Skip( i + 1 ));
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve: do you simply want to assert that `(100,101,102,103)` contains same elements of e.g. `(103,102,100,101)` ?

Comment: Does order matter? How should duplicates be considered?

Comment: Also, yours is not an array, but basically a matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
var leftHandSide = inputSequence.First();
var rightHandSideList = inputSequence.Skip(1);

rightHandSideList.All(s => s.SequenceEqual(leftHandSide));
```

Basically we take 1st element, and compare remaining with this. Here I'm assuming order matters. Also assuming list has at least 2 elements.

Comment: +1 `var res = rightHandSideList.All(s => s.OrderBy(_ => _).SequenceEqual(leftHandSide.OrderBy(_ => _)));` To ignore in-list orders.

Comment: My thinking was wonky: I only need to compare the first element with every subsequent element! So I don't need permutation or combinations in this scenario but I would like to know how to do it with my current approach so I'll ask another question. Thanks!